# Зависание программы из за асинхронной нити

Tags: c++, c++11, асинхронность, udp

Есть код:

```
bool UdpClient::stopListen = false;

void UdpClient::listen(SOCKET RecvSocket, sockaddr_in addr, onReceive o, UdpClient::onError _onError)
{
    int size = sizeof(addr);
    char rBuff[1024];
    int buffSize = sizeof(rBuff);
    while (!stopListen) {
        int err = recvfrom(RecvSocket, rBuff, sizeof(rBuff), 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, &buffSize);
        if (err > 0) {
            rBuff[err] = 0;
            if (o)
                o(rBuff);
        }
        else {
            if (_onError) {
                std::ostringstream out;

                out << "recv failed: " << WSAGetLastError();
                _onError(out.str());
            }
            closesocket(RecvSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
    }
}

void UdpClient::receive(onReceive r, int port, const std::string& ip)
{
    std::ostringstream out;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << iResult;
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in ServerAddr;
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &ServerAddr.sin_addr);

    SOCKET RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (RecvSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "socket failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    int err = bind(RecvSocket, (sockaddr*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr));
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();         
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        closesocket(RecvSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    std::async(std::launch::async, listen, RecvSocket, ServerAddr, r, _onError);
    //std::thread(listen, RecvSocket, ServerAddr, r, _onError);
}
```

Почему зависает вся программа, если listen выполняется в отдельной нити? Зависание происходит на строке с recvfrom.
И ещё один вопрос. Есть ли библиотека сокетов под x64? Насколько понимаю, используется Ws2_32.lib.

Comment: Ws2_32.lib это библиотека импорта под x64 (при импорте под x86 используется отличная библиотека с тем же именем)

Comment: Странно, конечно же, видеть имя переменной `err` для размера принятых данных, но дело не в этом. А в том, что если переменная `stopListen` меняет свое значение во внешней функции (например, в `(*o)(char[])`), то как минимум ее надо объявлять с атрибутом `volatile` / А вообще ..., бросьте вы эту новомодную бесовщину. Для работы по событиям используйте `epoll` (если он есть в винде), ну или обычный `poll` (хоть он то в ней есть?)

Comment: Какая стандартная ошибка, волатайл вовсе не для этого. Я пишу с восьмидесятых, многопоточности учился по книге дейкстры, в которой про мьютекс, так вот в данном случае статическая переменная вполне подходит. Вы извините, что не делюсь всем своим опытом, правила против, а на писанину в форумах не заработал репутации.

Comment: В самом деле, еще лет 10 назад компайлеры до такого беспредела с оптимизацией как сейчас не доходили. Volatile как раз и говорит, что все обращения к переменной должны менять память. (кстати, я тоже программирую с 70-х (если институт зачесть), потом учился по сорсам bsd) / И еще, извиняюсь, но тут `(sockaddr*)&addr, &buffSize` в `buffSize` нужно записать размер `*addr` (впрочем, много не мало -), переменная `buffSize`  будет модифицирована в `recvfrom()` актуальным размером адреса отправителя

Comment: Будьте внимательней. Код изначально не мой, оттуда и имя err, ошибку в нём, когда в переменную с размером буффера писалась требуемая для принятия длина, заметил и исправил. Здесь проблема не в оптимизации. В семидесятых я учился в школе, но уже тогда дома были префокарты, родители с работы приносили, чтобы не пропадали в мусорке, это сейчас о бумаге не думают (но не я).

Comment: Почитайте комментарии про волайтл, Ваша ошибка давно известна. Волатайл не для конкурентного, как сейчас модно называть, программирования, а для работы с железом.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa, если хотите, чтобы визави получал notification, пишите @nick перед комментарием. По делу же, вы утверждаете, что вызвали `o(rBuff)`, она записала `true` в `stopListen`, однако внутри цикла `while (!stopListen) { ... }` в функции `UdpClient::listen` значение переменной `stopListen` не изменилось?

Comment: @avp, а писать это обращение вручную, как вот сейчас Вам? Сейчас скопирую вызов и останов из внешней функции. Может как то можно добавлять код в этот же комментарий, как в первом сообщении? Пробовал и ctrl-enter нажимать, всё равно не строка переводится, а комментарий отправляется.

Comment: int main()
    {
        UdpClient udpClient(onError);
        udpClient.receive(onReceive, 512, "127.0.0.1");
        cout << "Press any key to exit..." << endl;
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        UdpClient::stopListen = true;
        return 0;
    }

Comment: В других программах работает как ожидается, здесь же до этого не доходит, на recvfrom происходит зависание всей программы, а не только нити. То есть вызов не асинхронный, в том же потоке.

Comment: Да, `@` сработала, я получил notification. Форматирование в комментариях практически отсутствует, можно сделать *\*italic\**, **\*\*bold\*\*** и `\`выделить текст\``. Почему в винде `recvfrom()` блокирует все потоки не знаю (в ней не пишу). Попробуйте спросить  конкретно об этом знатоков винды в новом вопросе, сопроводив его минимальным законченным примером кода.

Comment: Спасибо, @avp !

Answer (score 2):

`std::async` возвращает вам `std::future`, которая в деструкторе ждет завершения потока. Вам нужно или куда-нибудь сохранить возвращенную `std::future`, или же нужно вернуться к использованию `std::thread`:

```
std::thread(listen, RecvSocket, ServerAddr, r, _onError).detach()
```

Comment: В том то и дело, всё это проверял, не помогает. Могу выложить архив решения, чтобы сами могли убедиться. В деббагере отлаживаю, захожу в лисен по асинхронному вызову (асинк или трид), нить зависает в указанном месте, что нормально, но в вызванное место не возращается, до разрушения фьючерса (если с асинком) дело не доходит.

Comment: Например через вызов нити следующее сообщение: udpTest.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова., произошло... abort. С асинком возвращал из receive зашаренный фьючерс, но до этого не доходило, возврата из запущенной задачи не происходит (ставил останов после в дебаггере).

Comment: @SawaAkisawa а как вы проверяли что "в вызванное место не возвращается"? Вы точку останова в функции receive ставить пробовали?

Comment: Конечно, ставил точку останова. Не возвращается.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa а в перкменную результат вы сохраеили?

Comment: Это вы про auto f=std::async? Сохранял и пытался возвратить в вызывающую функцию. Но не возвращается.

Answer (score 0):

Вам всё правильно говорят, всё что надо это сохранить результат в переменную.
Вот минимальный слушатель удп

```
#include <future>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

bool stopListen = false;

int llisten(SOCKET RecvSocket, sockaddr_in addr)
{
    int size = sizeof(addr);
    char rBuff[1024];
    int buffSize = sizeof(rBuff);

    while (stopListen == false) 
    {
        int err = recvfrom(RecvSocket, rBuff, sizeof(rBuff), 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, &buffSize);
        if (err > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "received: " << std::string(rBuff, err)  << std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "recv failed: " << WSAGetLastError();
            closesocket(RecvSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 44444;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << iResult;
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in ServerAddr;
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &ServerAddr.sin_addr);

    SOCKET RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (RecvSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        std::cout << "socket failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    int err = bind(RecvSocket, (sockaddr*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr));
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(RecvSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, llisten, RecvSocket, ServerAddr);

    std::cout << "Here we are" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    stopListen = true;
    shutdown(RecvSocket, SD_BOTH); // Останавливаем сокет, прерываем блок recvfrom с ошибкой WSAEINTR
    closesocket(RecvSocket); // Закрываем сокет
    system("pause");
 }
```

Выхлоп:

```
Here we are
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . . received: hello world

recv failed: 10004
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Дополнительно:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535028/is-stdasync-guaranteed-to-be-called-for-functions-returning-void

Дополнительно 2:
Изменение `stopListen = true;` не прервет выполняющийся блокирующий вызов `recvfrom` и не остановит поток, чтобы это сделать надо использовать другие методы: или неблокирующий опрос или переходить на полл

Comment: а то не сохранял и не пытался даже вернуть. Не доходит до сохранения!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь, вот решение:

```
bool UdpClient::stopListen = false;

void UdpClient::listen(SOCKET RecvSocket, sockaddr_in addr, onReceive o, UdpClient::onError _onError)
{
    int size = sizeof(addr);
    char rBuff[1024];
    int buffSize = sizeof(rBuff);
    while (stopListen) {
        int err = recvfrom(RecvSocket, rBuff, sizeof(rBuff), 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, &buffSize);
        if (err > 0) {
            rBuff[err] = 0;
            if (o)
                o(rBuff);
        }
        else {
            if (_onError) {
                std::ostringstream out;

                out << "recv failed: " << WSAGetLastError();
                _onError(out.str());
            }
            closesocket(RecvSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
    }
}

std::shared_future<void> UdpClient::receive(onReceive r, int port, const std::string& ip)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    std::future<void> k;
    std::shared_future<void> m;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << iResult;
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        return m;
    }

    sockaddr_in ServerAddr;
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &ServerAddr.sin_addr);

    SOCKET RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (RecvSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "socket failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        WSACleanup();
        return m;
    }

    int err = bind(RecvSocket, (sockaddr*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr));
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();         
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        closesocket(RecvSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return m;
    }

    auto n = std::async(std::launch::async, listen, RecvSocket, ServerAddr, r, _onError).share();
    //std::shared_future<std::future<void>> f(n);
    return n;
}
```