# Невозможность асинхронного вызова recvfrom()

Tags: c++, windows, websocket, concurrency, асинхронность

[Вызов recvfrom() из вызванной асинхронно функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933935/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment1551468_933935) блокирует не только нить, в которой функция, но и вызывавший поток (возврат в него не происходит). Почему и как это обойти?

ps Это, если верно считаю, уже третья тема по советам переформулировать и задать новый вопрос в предыдущих, где никто ничем не смог помочь, в чём любой может убедиться, если почитает предыдущие темы внимательно, а именно мои комментарии к ответам.

pps
[vs2017 solution](http://amsawa.narod.ru/data/udp.rar)

Comment: Там же уже ответили

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зависание программы из за асинхронной нити](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933935/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8)

Comment: "Попробуйте спросить конкретно об этом знатоков винды в новом вопросе, **сопроводив его минимальным законченным примером кода**."

Answer (score 0):

recvfrom - блокирующая функция (ОС Виндовс)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom

...

> if no incoming data is available at the socket, the recvfrom function
>   blocks and waits for data to arrive according to the blocking rules
>   defined for WSARecv with the MSG_PARTIAL flag not set unless the
>   socket is nonblocking. In this case, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is
>   returned with the error code set to WSAEWOULDBLOCK. The select,
>   WSAAsyncSelect, or WSAEventSelect can be used to determine when more
>   data arrives.

...

Попробуйте использовать асинхронные операции
WSA2:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsarecv

<del>std::async не гарантирует выполнения в отдельном потоке и содержит кучу ограничений на асинхронный запуск, и, вполне естественно, что у вас зависает весь поток.</del>

Comment: Флажок `std::launch::async` как раз гарантирует выполнение в отдельном потоке, а основной поток у ОПа записает из-за непраильного использования, как то было объяснено в ответе к оригинальному вопросу

Comment: Использование правильное, просто там выложено то, что сейчас осталось после многократных редакций. Будьте внимательней -- я там же ответил, что пробовал ВОЗВРАЩАТЬ фьючерс, то есть деструктор его не вызывается раньше, чем остановлю статической переменной. Кроме того, thread подавно должен работать, а не работает. Вот за WSAAsyncSelect спасибо, попробую копать в этом направлении.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa, а чем плох отдельный поток? вы же так или иначе запускаете бесконечный цикл

Comment: @SawaAkisawa Нет, использование у вас не правильное. А если вы что-то пробовали и оно тоже не работало, то надо было создать новый вопрос, и привести в нем **новый** полноценный пример с конкретной проблемой. Собственно ответ там относится к приведенному коду, а не к какому-то другому, которого кроме вас никто не видел.  `WSAAsyncSelect` это вообще устаревшая функция, которой пользоваться не стоит

Comment: @goldstar_labs, проблема в том, что блокируется вся задача со всеми потоками.

Comment: @VTT, в чём неправильное, конкретно? А выложить решение для экспериментов я предложил в самом начале, да никто не изъявил желания. Ещё раз повторяю, дело до деструктора фьючерса не доходит! И закоментаренный вариант с thread  тоже проверялся, там нет никаких деструкторов! Опять теоретики невнимательные нападают...

Comment: @SawaAkisawa Там же уже ответили... С закоментированным вариантом вообще совсем другая проблема, не связанная с первой, которая однозначно заслуживает отдельного вопроса. А решение для экспериментов имеет смысл выкладывать только как дополнение к [минимальному, самодостаточному и воспроизводимому примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в самом вопросе. Еще хочу отметить, что минимальный пример для обоих этих проблем укладывается все в пару строк. Не надо выкладывать полотна.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa, все потоки останавливаются только дебагером в точке останова, асинк может заблокировать только вызывающий поток

Comment: @VTT, хотел выложить архив vs2017 solution на свой сайт и дать здесь на него ссылку. Сделать? Наверное, надо отредактировать вопрос в одной из тем, в какой?

Comment: @SawaAkisawa лучше соберите минимальный вопроизводимый пример, чтобы его можно было скопировать-вставить и проверить работу

Comment: @goldstar_labs, async здесь ничего не блокирует, блокирует функция.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa, яннп, так а в чем проблема? вы вызываете блокирующую функцию, она блокируется, чтобы вызывающий поток не блокировался, сохраните результат в future

Comment: Выложил решение в этой теме. Убедитесь, чтобы мне в сотый раз не повторять одно и то же.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa, ну так у вас в коде вызов `std::async` мы добавляем `auto f = std::async` и всё начинает работать (т.е. вызывающий поток не блокируется и выводится текст "Press any key to exit...")

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь, вот решение:

```
bool UdpClient::stopListen = false;

void UdpClient::listen(SOCKET RecvSocket, sockaddr_in addr, onReceive o, UdpClient::onError _onError)
{
    int size = sizeof(addr);
    char rBuff[1024];
    int buffSize = sizeof(rBuff);
    while (stopListen) {
        int err = recvfrom(RecvSocket, rBuff, sizeof(rBuff), 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, &buffSize);
        if (err > 0) {
            rBuff[err] = 0;
            if (o)
                o(rBuff);
        }
        else {
            if (_onError) {
                std::ostringstream out;

                out << "recv failed: " << WSAGetLastError();
                _onError(out.str());
            }
            closesocket(RecvSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
    }
}

std::shared_future<void> UdpClient::receive(onReceive r, int port, const std::string& ip)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    std::future<void> k;
    std::shared_future<void> m;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << iResult;
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        return m;
    }

    sockaddr_in ServerAddr;
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &ServerAddr.sin_addr);

    SOCKET RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (RecvSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "socket failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        WSACleanup();
        return m;
    }

    int err = bind(RecvSocket, (sockaddr*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr));
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (_onError) {
            out << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();         
            _onError(out.str());
        }
        closesocket(RecvSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return m;
    }

    auto n = std::async(std::launch::async, listen, RecvSocket, ServerAddr, r, _onError).share();
    //std::shared_future<std::future<void>> f(n);
    return n;
}
```